# Echoing the Counts of each record through PHP using SOQL and GROUP BY

Tags: soql, force.com, php, aggregate, count

To start, this is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT LeadSource, COUNT(id) Total 
          FROM Lead 
          WHERE CreatedDate > 2013-08-26T00:00:00Z 
                  AND CreatedDate < 2013-08-26T14:00:00Z 
          GROUP BY ROLLUP(LeadSource)";
$options = new QueryOptions(500);
$sf->setQueryOptions($options);
$response = $sf->query($query);
```

When I run this query in Force.com Explorer, it's beautiful. It shows the LeadSource and the Total column, no problem. Here's the result:

[image]

I'm trying to pull the information into PHP and I tested the content with:

```
print '<pre>'; print_r($response); print '</pre>';
```

(I use the pre to read the output more easily.)

The result of this code in my PHP is that it tells me I have 26 records (true) and lists the LeadSource of each of the records. What it's not doing is give me the counts within each record. (Shown here:)

[image]

How do I get that number to print out via PHP (like it is in the first image), not just through Force.com Explorer?

Continuation: I'm trying to go around the situation by pulling it out of the aggregate query and performing a query to create an array to create a query. I'm not fond of this solution, as it's clunky and not very intuitive...so I would still appreciate any advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the data as csv and then importing it into PHP? This sounds essentially like a data transfer issue. Most data is usually transferred in and out of SF as csv and could be a formatting issue once it arrives into PHP.

Comment: I'm confused. PHP is not a package or software, it's a scripting language. I'm coding in PHP to create a web-based charting & reporting tool that combines the Salesforce information with information in other databases. You can't "import" into PHP.

Comment: I'm just going to add that I've tried an aggregate function with the query() API call in PHP and am having the same issue. I've tested on Lead and a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

User php toolkit and to print out the response do something like this :

```
$mySforceConnection->getLastResponse();
```

Next you'll have soap envelope that you need to parse.